Solving equations involving union and intersection of sets
I am trying to solve the following equation for $B$ in terms of $A$ and $C$; $A \cap B = C$.
Here's my attempt.
I know that sets are associative and distributive over union and intersection.
Therefore given $A \cap B = C$
Add $B^{c}$ to both sides
$(A \cap B) \cap B^{c} = C \cap B^{c}$
We obtain
$(A \cap B^{c}) \cap (B \cap B^{c}) = C \cap B^{c}$
$(A \cap B^{c}) \cap \emptyset = C \cap B^{c}$
Or
$\emptyset = C \cap B^{c}$
Apply union on both sides yields
$\emptyset \cup B = (C \cap B^{c}) \cup B$
$B = (C \cup B) \cap (B^{c} \cup B)$
$B = (C \cup B) \cap U$
$B = (C \cup B)$
Or
$\emptyset \cup B = C \cup B$
By comparison we conclude that:
$C = \emptyset$
That's what I arrived at but something doesn't seem right to me

Your final conclusion is wrong, there is no rule allowing you to eliminate $B$ from the unions on both sides of the equation in the last step. All you can conclude there is that $C\subset B.$

The condition $A \cap B=C$ does not determine $B$ uniquely (within a given universe $\Omega$) even if $A$ and $C$ are given. For example put $\Omega=\{1,2,3\},$ $A=\{1,2\}$ and $C=\{1\}$ then we can never know if $B=\{1\}$ or $B=\{1,3\}.$
If $C\subset A$ then the general solution is the union of $C$ with any subset of $A^c$, the complement of $A$. That is, $B \in \{C \cup A' : A' \in \mathcal{P}(A^c)\}$, so the number of possible solutions is $2^{|A^c|}$.
If $C\not\subset A$ then there are no solutions.

I have edited the last sentence back in because the fact that $C$ is a subset of $A$ is not given in the original problem statement.
